# Scrolling down to the comments when clicking "n deleted comments" doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools

- My URL bar is set to: [What is the Vim8 package feature and how should I use it?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i-use-it/95233)
- I click on the "13 deleted comments" link for the top answer (only visible for mods).
- Nothing appears to happen.
- I need to scroll down to see the comments.

I would expect it to scroll down to the first comment.

---

*Update*: after checking Chromium it appears to work there! I'm using Firefox 50.1.0 on Linux. All extensions disabled. I have JS etc. enabled (no funky settings there). There are no errors in my console.

Comment: I think this would be a good idea, but not by adding `#comment16605_9523` to the URL. If this can be done dynamically without modifying the URL then I'm for this. (It does seem like a lot of work for little gain though; the button's (usually) going to make the list longer so there's little point auto-scrolling through it.)

Comment: What browser/version are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this in Chrome for a Mac

Comment: It *does* scroll down. You need JS enabled, and the moderator JS loaded.

Comment: @bluefeet Strange. I'm using Firefox 50.1.0 on Linux. All extensions disabled. I have JS etc. enabled (no funky settings there). I also checked Chromium on the same system and it does work there, so seems like a Firefox specific problem (?) There are no errors in my console.

Comment: @ArtOfCode "the moderator JS"? I've never observed the scrolldown, using mostly Firefox on Windows, Mac, Linux.